# LDA accuracy is higher for reduced dataset than for original

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, linear-discriminant

I'm trying to reduce a dataset with [LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit_transform). I expect that on reduced dataset I will have less accuracy. However, depending on the random seed I get sometimes the reduced version is giving me higher accuracy.

```
X, y = make_classification(1000, 50, n_informative=10, n_classes=20)
X1, X2, y1, y2 = train_test_split(X, y)

lda = LDA()
lda.fit(X1, y1)
predicted = lda.predict(X2)
full_accuracy = accuracy_score(y2, predicted)


reduction = LDA(n_components=5)
X1red = reduction.fit_transform(X1, y1)
X2red = reduction.transform(X2)


lda.fit(X1red, y1)
predicted = lda.predict(X2red)
reduced_accuracy = accuracy_score(predicted, y2)

print full_accuracy, reduced_accuracy, reduced_accuracy/full_accuracy


# prints 0.132 0.16 1.21212121212
```

Do you know why after dimensionality reduction I have higher accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a **guarantee** that reduced dimensionality will be either better or worse. You are applying two weak models separately, from time to time you can get lucky and they will actually cancel outs weaknesses and get slightly better than the weak model applied directly. In general, dimensionality reduction should not increase dimensionality **given that** you have enough data, and the model you are fitting is **strong**. LDA is not a strong model (it is extremely naive one) thus you might end up with various results.

For some more intuition lets take a look at an extremely simple example

```
X = 0 900
    1 1000
    2 123
    3 123124
    4 1251251   

y = 0 1 0 1 0
```

and my model is a function `f(x|theta) = sum(x) % theta`, where I learn `theta`. If I just apply this to my data directly I will be able to learn that since

```
f(X) = 900 % theta
       1001 % theta
       125 % theta
       123127 % theta
       1251255 % theta
```

the best theta is `theta=2` as then I get predictions `0 1 1 1 1`, with 60% accuracy. Now lets apply dimensionality reduction technique, which is extremely simple in my case, it is `g(x) = x[0]`, thus

```
g(X) = 0
       1
       2
       3
       4
```

and if I now compose `f o g` (apply my model to the reduced data) I will again learn that `theta=2`, but this time my predictions are `0 1 0 1 0`, 100% accuracy!

At the same time I could choose different dimensonality reduction, like `g(x)=x[1]` and get instead `0 0 1 0 1`, which is just 20% accuracy! Thus worse than original.

As you can see, you can always get both - better or worse. Since dimensonality reduction technique is applied **without the knowledge what follows**, it can do arbitrary good/bad things. No guarantees.